# used dd to clone ssd but won't boot

Tags: hard-drive

Have a lenovo 32bit running 18.04 with a 1Tb drive. Tried cloning the drive to a ssd (1Tb) took days but seemed to eork fine. The drive looks great is bootable, has the same uuid but won't boot.

Comment: Are you running **18.04 32bit**? This sounds strange since Ubuntu has stopped 32 bit version of Ubuntu at least.

Comment: Cloning may fail, if the target drive has a different size than the original one, particularly if it is smaller (it should not be one single byte smaller). Also, never boot a computer with two identical partition tables and file system. So please shutdown, unplug the cloned copy, boot into the original drive, then connect the cloned copy and run the following command lines, `df` and `sudo lsblk  -f` and `sudo lsblk -m` and `sudo parted -ls` -- Edit your original question to add the output of the commands. Indent each line 4 spaces to render the output as 'code'. This will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I originally copied using `dd /hdd1 /hdd2` and it took 2.5 days to clone. I found a comment regarding dealing with errors and ran `fsck` from the initramfs prompt. The SSD did then boot but trying to look at two identical drives (as [sudodus noted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066671/used-dd-to-clone-ssd-but-wont-boot#comment1747959_1066671)) implied directory inconsistencies.

Finally tried

```
dd if=/hhd1 of=/hhd2 bs=64K conv=noerror,sync
```

again. I had to run `fsck` but this time `e2.fsck` and all looks good.

I'm running a 32bit Lenovo Ultra and Bionic Beaver seems to run well... SSD is faster and I hope the old battery will run longer.

Comment: I apologize for the sloppy note..that should be: dd if=/hhd1 of=hhd2 bs=64K conv=noerror,sync

Comment: You should [edit] your answers to correct mistakes, not post them in comments. I’ve done it this time for you.